# Matching "uniqid" with corresponding sex and age.

Tags: r, reshape

I have a dataframe `imcds` from a survey  that asked sex and age information of every person in the household to the householder. So the householder would be Person 1 and the rest of the people would be person 2, 3, 4 .. etc... thus:

```
uniqid  Age1  Age2  Age3  Sex1  Sex2  Sex3

1012501  9     7      5     1    2      1
1012502  9     7      5     1    2      1
1012503  9     7      5     1    2      1
1012601  8     5      NA    2    1      NA
1012602  8     5      NA    2    1      NA
```

The first five numbers of the `uniqid` are the household ID and the last two are the person identifier. Therefore, the Age value of Person `1012503` is `Age3` (5), and Sex is `Sex3` (1). What I want to do is reshape the data frame `imcds` into something like this:

```
uniqid  Age  Sex  

1012501  9     1      
1012502  7     2      
1012503  5     1      
1012601  8     2      
1012602  5     1
```

Each `uniqid` with their correspondent `Sex` and `Age` values.The data frame has 2095 obs of 583 variables. Do I need a loop? What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We extract the substring from 6 to 7 characters in the 'uniqid' column, use that to create row/column index ('ind'), extract the corresponding elements from 'Age' columns and 'Sex' columns, and `cbind` with the first column of the dataset.

```
ind <- cbind(1:nrow(df1), as.numeric(substr(df1$uniqid, 6,7)))
Age <- df1[grep("Age", names(df1))][ind]
Sex <- df1[grep("Sex", names(df1))][ind]
df2 <- cbind(df1[1], Age, Sex)
df2
#   uniqid Age Sex
#1 1012501   9   1
#2 1012502   7   2
#3 1012503   5   1
#4 1012601   8   2
#5 1012602   5   1
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked great. But how do I modify the df itself? to add `Age` and `Sex` as new columns of the original `imcds` data.frame ?? To then just drop `Age1`, `Age2`, ... `Age7` and be left with one unique column with the age and sex of each `uniqid`.

Comment: @GracielaCarrillo   You can create a new object with `df2 <- cbind(df1[1], ...` (updated teh post

Comment: @GracielaCarrillo If we need to create new columns in the original dataset, just do `df1[c("Age", "Sex")] <- list(Age, Sex)`